# how to dismiss MPMoviePlayer ? properly from one ViewController to another

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using the Notification Center to receive the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, which works as expected.

```
   NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://INFINITECREATIVEUNIVERSE.COM/Media/module_1_Dec/c_January27AffactPerfect.mov"];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 260)];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    //Some addiontal customization
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    //moviePlayer.endPlaybackTime = NO;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playMovieFinished:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];
```

The selector does what I would like it to do.

```
-(void)playMovieFinished:(NSNotification*)theNotification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:moviePlayer];
    //                     Change Segue ID Here    

    [self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VC_5" sender:self];
}
```

My problem occurs when I click next button while the video is still playing. When my next ViewController appears there is no video and I can still hear the audio from the previous ViewController.

My question is:
How do I properly dismiss the View Controller and the MPMoviePlayer.
I am lost.
I downloaded the example MoviePlayer project from Apple, but it is now deprecated and it does not work properly. 
I am lost on how to make this work.
I am crossing my fingers that I have asked the question correctly. Please have mercy on my novice question. Thank you robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
-(void)playMovieFinished:(NSNotification*)theNotification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:moviePlayer];
    [moviePlayer stop];
    // Change Segue ID Here    

    [self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VC_5" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: First of all, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. Yes that worked when you click Done in the MoviePlayer if I switch from MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded

Comment: to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen. Where can I find documentation on custom MoviePlayer Buttons? For I want to add a Done Button in my Menu Bar. THANK YOU AGAIN. robert

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. I will do a new post for a AVFoundation. Since that is more of a AV question. I am starting to understand more on how xCode iOS is working. But I am far from a pro. Thank you again.

Comment: sorry but not getting in terms of what you're asking.. do you need an document on custom MoviePlayer? or you need any document on AVFoundation?